# Wireless 7260 stopped working after update

Tags: 20.04, iwlwifi

After recent automatic updates, the wireless stopped connecting totally and keeps on trying without succeeding. If I add  `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`  in  `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` file, it starts to connect again but the speed is unacceptably lowsy on this already slow 150Mbps connection.

I have dual boot on this Dell M4800 with Win10. With 7260 card on Ubuntu, I get about 10 Mbps speed while on Win10 about 50Mbps. I now have to use (an unbranded) USB wifi dongle with Ubuntu and that gives me the same speeds as on the Windows side. I have tried the backport driver but that does not help in any way, so please what should I do next?

PS.

Before the recent updates, the speeds were the same on both Ubuntu and Win10 using the 7260 card.

I'm on 20.04 and the Kernel version is 5.8.0-32-generic. The situation is the same if I boot to 5.4.0-56-generic. I had version 5.6 at some point but autoremove has removed it so I can't roll back to test that. I don't know how to log all the recent updates that have been installed after all being OK.

2020-12-24 The problem has not been solved. The symptoms are identical to what can be read from this thread:

[linux-surface kernel issue](https://github.com/linux-surface/kernel/issues/54)

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? What were "the recent updates"? Try to boot with a previous kernel. If it works well there, then report a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I added the answer to the original post as PS.